# Empty Heading HTML warning

Tags: html

I'm doing a w3c check on my website and I came across an odd error:

```
Warning: Empty heading.
From line 106, column 9; to line 106, column 12
>↩<header><h1><a href="/recipes.html"></a></h1></header>↩
```

from my mild googling it seems like it wants content after the  tag, but that I am supposed to put an  inside a header tag.

What's the correct syntax here? I believe the template I'm using has CSS attached to the header tag, is the reason it's there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your header tag doesn't have any text within it(the a tag is empty).

Comment: It's only a warning, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: `<header><h1><a href="/recipes.html"></a></h1></header>` remove it(`<` )

Answer (score 0):

```
    <header>
     <h1><a href="link">Some message</a></h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers. Yours is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this ....

```
<header>
<h1><a href="/recipes.html">My Recipes</a></h1>
</header>
```

The link tag didn't have a text.